# What theme was used to make the Jekyll homepage

Tags: themes, jekyll

Was the Jekyll home page made with Jekyll? And if so what theme did they use and is it publicly available.

I recently noticed that the site [dev assets](http://devassets.com) looks very similar to the Jekyll home page and uses Jekyll, however while looking through the source I could not find the name of the theme in any of the config files.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went through the [`docs/`](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/tree/master/docs) directory of the [`jekyll`](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll) repository. They're definitely using Jekyll. In [`_sass/`](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/tree/master/docs/_sass), only two files are not original:

- [`_gridism.scss`](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/blob/master/docs/_sass/_gridism.scss), GitHub Repo: [`gridism`](https://github.com/cobyism/gridism)
- [`_normalize.scss`](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/blob/master/docs/_sass/_normalize.scss), GitHub Repo: [`normalize.css`](https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css)

All the rest are essentially original, as in the developers of the website made the theme themselves.